# Como subtrair e somar datas com javascript?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Estou com duas datas e preciso fazer um delta dessas datas para adicionar nas seguintes. Veja abaixo:

data1 = 2020-08-14T10:02
data2 = 2020-08-14T10:07

O código abaixo traz a diferença dessas datas:

```
var a = moment('2020-08-14T10:02');
var b = moment('2020-08-14T10:07');

console.log(b.diff(a, 'minutes'))
console.log(b.diff(a, 'hours'))
console.log(b.diff(a, 'days'))
console.log(b.diff(a, 'weeks'))

//5
//0
//0
//0
```

Agora eu quero que a data3 seja "2020-08-14T10:07" e adicionar os 5 minutos de diferença na data4, podem me ajudar?

Comment: Ja ouviu falar do date-fns? Ele tem umas funções bem interessantes

Answer (score -1):

Como o objeto `Moment` implementa o método `valueOf` para retornar o tempo em milissegundos, você pode apenas subtrair os objetos para capturar a diferença.

Depois use o método `add` para adicionar a diferença na sua data. Porém o método `add` não gera um novo objeto, ele modifica o objeto que invoca o método, se você quer gerar um objeto `Moment` separado, clone o objeto anterior com o método `clone` antes de adicionar a diferênça:

```js
var a = moment('2020-08-14T10:02');
var b = moment('2020-08-14T10:07');

var diff = b - a;
var c = b.clone().add(diff, 'millisecond');
var d = c.clone().add(diff); // informar que a diferença é em milissegundos é opcional

// isso também é possível graças ao método valueOf, 
// mas se você gerar uma nova data a partir dos milissegundos, 
// você irá perder o fuso horário dessa data
var e = moment(d + diff);

console.log('a:', a);
console.log('b:', b);
console.log('c:', c);
console.log('d:', d);
console.log('e:', e);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Muito bem explicado e este parece ser mesmo o caminho, mas estranho que para mim a var d está pegando a mesma data de c e não está adicionando a diferença.

Comment: Você gerou `d` a partir de um clone de `c`?

Comment: Sim, ficou desta forma: var d = c.clone().add(diff);